# I'm getting a syntax error involving something in these lines

Tags: javascript, html, css

Dreamweaver is telling me I have a syntax error here, but not telling me what it is or exactly where.

I am including a javascript file and a css file in my html document, so I'm assuming I wrote something wrong in the code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pizza0-1style.css" />
<script src="pizza0-1displayscript.js" />
```

EDIT: They are in the head of my document..is that where they should be?

Comment: Yes, head is a good place for external scripts and stylesheets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try closing the script tag this way:

```
<script src="pizza0-1displayscript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try putting it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pizza0-1displayscript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot self close a `script` tag.

**Correct**

```
<script></script>
```

**Incorrect**

```
<script />
```

**Event more incorrect**

```
<script><script><span/><a><br><script />
```

Comment: Technically, “self-closing” `script` tag in valid in XHTML but not recommended in real life, or “for authors who wish their XHTML documents to render on existing HTML user agents” as the HTML compatibility guidelines in XHTML 1.0 spec put it: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines